# Reason for javascript disabled in drupal site?

Tags: multi-sites

I am using multisite module to maintain three sites. In that i have used "hierarchical_select" module for a form.

In one of my multisite this form is working great, But in the same form for other site, I am getting following error.

I have attached a screen shot of the error.

As it is using the same files, i am thinking that it should be an configuration issues. But i have checked thrice for all the configuration and unsuccessful.

Please help.

Thanks in advance for any help
[image]

Comment: Could it be a wrong path to the .js file because of the multisite feature?

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchical select adds that info box but removes it with JavaScript. This means that this error can happen for three reasons:

- The `hierarchical_select.js` file is not loaded on the page.
- You have an js error on the page before the `hierarchical_select.js` file is executed.
- You have changed the markup for that info box, so that it is not removed by the JavaScript.

The most obvious reason is a that a JavaScript error breaks this page for you, but that is something you'll have to debug yourself...

To do so open [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox or the preinstalled Developer Tools on Chrome (strg+shift+i). If you use firebug first enable the Console. Then reload the page and if there is a Javascript Error it will be indicated  with a red warning.